# Index use and column type

Tags: mysql, index

I was told today that having a table structure similar to this is bad for performance of indexes because of the mismatch of column types.

Table 1 
id - int (7) PK 
Others ....

Table 2
id int (11) Index    (has to exist in table 1 logically - though not enforced through FK)
Others ....

I'm using MySQL with InnoDB.

The question I suppose could also be related to Varchar 200 vs 220 for example.

I know that the index size will be affected by the extra space per item needed (and storage space in general), probably in the 5-10% area, but will the time taken for joins to happen increase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phrases like *bad for performance* are essentially meaningless. Measurements are  meaningful; opinions are, umm, not measurements.

But `int(7)` and `int(11)` are both 32-bit integers. The number in parens refers to display width; it has nothing to do with storage size or index size.

For `varchar()` columns, you *can* create an index that's based on the first 'n' characters. *That* decision has some performance implications, for example when you're searching for 'wibble' in a column indexed on the first three characters. And there are several subtle points with columns of type "text". Read [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) carefully. (Search for "length".)

But I'd be a little surprised if you could measure any difference in joining columns of `varchar(200)`/`varchar(200`) and in joining columns of `varchar(220)`/`varchar(200)`. That is, other than the obvious--storing more than 200 characters in the `varchar(220)` column.

There's an easy way to tell: write some code in your favorite scripting language, generate a few million rows of sample data, load it, and test it. And post your results here, too.

Comment: To put it more bluntly: specifying a width for `int` at a database level is asinine and asking for trouble.